# MySQL Query Copy entire row if is not equal

Tags: mysql

Good morning,

I'm trying to write the following query:

```
Copy the entire row of tabA to row of tabB
IF
tabA.column1 is different (or NULL) from tabB.column1
AND
tabA.column2 is different (or NULL) from tabB.column2
AND
tabA.column3 is different (or NULL) from tabB.column3
WHERE
tabA.colonnaDATE is greater than 30 days
```

Comment: *tabA.column1 is different (or NULL) from tabB.column1* - this condition is applicable to rows, no to tables. And "entire row of tabA" may be compared with any row of tabB giving sometimes TRUE, sometimes FALSE for the condition pack. Operate with the term "if exists a row in tabB where ..."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql Query Copy if is not equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64660808/mysql-query-copy-if-is-not-equal)

Comment: This is an exact copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64660808/mysql-query-copy-if-is-not-equal, that was closed because needs more details or needs to clarify. You didn't even make a question. You should help us to help you, and we need more information about your problem to help you. It is not a matter of asking the same question multiple times

Comment: what I intend to do is check from tableA if the date (column of tableA) is greater than 30 days then copy the whole row to tableB unless it is already there. Unfortunately I can't use id as a key because tableA changes every day and id will always be different